# Ansible, download msi file from general repo in Artifactory

Tags: ansible, artifactory

We manage our drops in Artifactory Generic repo. Now, we would like to deploy predefined version, let say located in MY_REPO/ver1/file.msi within the Artifactory.
How it can be done using ansible?
I've seen that ansible has maven_artifact but, would it work with the generic repo? How to pass the source path (MY_REPO/ver1/file.msi) ?
Seems that the maven_artifact works only on latest version and source path cannot be defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.htm) and by defining a special layout on your generic repository to detect the version.
in your case the layout would be "[orgPath]/ver[baseRev]/[module].[ext]"
with "Folder/File integration Revision Regexp" set to ".*"

then you have to deploy your msi respecting the layout : "MY_REPO/MY_ORG/ver1/file.msi"

doing that you can get the latest version using the following url : "[ARTIFACTORY_HOST]:[ARTIFACTORY_PORT]/artifactory/MY_REPO/MY_ORG/ver[RELEASE]/file.msi"

or use a parameter instead of [RELEASE] to get a specified version

so at the end this should work :

```
name: download latest msi using Artifactory API KEY
  get_url:
    url: [ARTIFACTORY_HOST]:[ARTIFACTORY_PORT]/artifactory/MY_REPO/MY_ORG/ver[RELEASE]/file.msi
    dest: [YOUR_DEST]
    headers: 'X-JFrog-Art-Api:[API_KEY]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Download README file from artifactory
  get_url:
    url: https://artifactoryServerName.jfrog.io/artifactoryServerName/example-repo-local/README.md
    headers:  "X-JFrog-Art-Api:API_KEY"
    dest: /tmp/
    mode: 0644
```

Where to find artifactory api key: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Updating+Your+Profile

Comment: in the user profile you can generate/get your API KEY (or re generate a new one). You can also create/get it with REST API : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateAPIKey